# Is it possible to right click an item in finder an "move to" to move a file / folder to another location?

Tags: macos, finder

Is there a way to get an option when using finder to be able the right click and select "move to", in the same way you can "move to trash". I'd like to be able to move items around my finder this way.

Usually when I've got my laptop connected to a larger monitor I just pull 2 finder windows side by side and drag and drop to organise folders, but it would be really useful when on a smaller laptop screen to be able to do this.

I'm running Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: Apple did build in a way to "move item here" but you first have to copy it (to maintain its integrity if anything untoward happens during the process) then use OPT+right click to move the copied item to its destination.

Answer (score 5):

I have a **Automator** *Service* named **Move Selected Items To....workflow** and shows on the *Context Menu* in **Finder** as **Move Selected Items To...** when *files* and or *folders* are selected. I can then choose where to move them to and whether or not to replace existing items.

Here's a picture of the *Services workflow* and note the settings under *Options* for the **Move Finder Items** *action*.

[image: Move Selected Items To....workflow picture]

Checking the **Show this action when the workflow runs** check box brings up the **Move Finder Items** *dialog box*, as shown in the image below, where you can the select where you want to move the *files*/*folders* to.

Note that you can change the default **To:** location from **Desktop** to wherever you'd like and then save the *Service* so it's what you chose as the starting point each time the service is triggered. While not shown in the example picture, I have it set to **Macintosh HD** so when the **Move Finder Items** *dialog box* appears, I can click the **Macintosh HD** and then **Other...** on the *popup menu* easily, to bring up the **Choose** *dialog box* to more quickly navigate to where I want to go.

[image: Move Finder Items dialog box]

You can also assign a *keyboard short* to the *Service* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **Files and Folders**. I assigned it: **^⌥⌘M**

---

Note: When I first saved the **Automator** *Service* it only showed two dots on the *Context Menu*, when I expected to see three as that is what I typed in the **Save service as:** *sheet*. Well, I had to rename it in **Finder** so there were four dots between **Move Selected Items To** and **workflow**, then save the file again pressing **⌘S** in **Automator**. This enabled the three dots to show on the *Context Menu* in **Finder**. Note that if you have more then a few *Services* it will appear under **Services** on the *Context Menu* in **Finder**.

I have since found out that had I used four dots in the **Save service as:** *sheet*, e.g. **Move Selected Items To....**, it would have then shown as **Move Selected Items To...** on the *Context Menu* without further meddling.

Answer (score 4):

If you select an item & either right click/Copy or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>C</kbd> 
then   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  will Paste to a new location, but  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  will Move, as will holding  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  as you right click; you'll see Paste change to Move.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to change shot cut keys to say use "Cmd ⌘  Opt ⌥  M" instead of "V" as i think that would be confusing in the long run where you may accidently copy a file as well as move it. Apart from that great solution

Comment: It's probably better to just remember it as "Paste Special", because Cmd/M is the system wide shortcut for 'Minimise Window' & Cmd/Opt/M is 'Minimise All Windows' - so you'd be fighting a lot of legacy structure to try persuade it to do that. If you forget & Paste instead, you only need to then delete the original.